# Import ES6 Module from local script

Tags: javascript, import, module, ecmascript-6, export

Lets say I import the following html file with

```
<link rel="import" href="somefile.html">
```

and the somefile.html looks like this:

```
<template>
    <some-tags>...</some-tags>
</template>

<script type="module">
    export default { some object }
</script>
```

Normally I would import a es6 module like so

```
import MyVariable from 'somefile.js'
```

but in this case I cannot point to the html file and I don't know how to import the module I imported through the link. Is that even possible or do I need to replace the export default with a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module support in browsers is very new and being done in small bites. As far as I can tell from [what specification we have for this so far](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system), the only module specifiers currently supported are URLs that refer to a JavaScript resource. The export you've shown can't currently be imported. From that linked spec:

> To resolve a module specifier given a script script and a JavaScript string specifier, perform the following steps. It will return either a URL record or failure.
>
> 1. Apply the URL parser to specifier. If the result is not failure, return the result.
> 2. If specifier does not start with the character U+002F SOLIDUS (/), the two-character sequence U+002E FULL STOP, U+002F SOLIDUS (./), or the three-character sequence U+002E FULL STOP, U+002E FULL STOP, U+002F SOLIDUS (../), return failure.
>
>    This restriction is in place so that in the future we can allow custom module loaders to give special meaning to "bare" import specifiers, like import "jquery" or import "web/crypto". For now any such imports will fail, instead of being treated as relative URLs.
> 3. Return the result of applying the URL parser to specifier with script's base URL as the base URL.

Instead, move that export into its own file and import it with a module specifier referring to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You might extract the code into a another file, e.g. `somefile.js` :

```
export default {
 //...
};
```

Then you can import that in your template:

```
<template>
    <some-tags>...</some-tags>
</template>

<script type="module">
    import somefile from "somefile.js";
    //... Whatever
</script>
```

And in any other code... Note that you currently must use webpack or a similar system to convert your code to ES6. Javascript modules are not well supported yet.